# How to resolve Ember deprecation: "Use defineProperty to define computed properties"

Tags: ember.js

While attempting to update an Ember application to Ember 3.6 (currently on the 3.4 LTS), I have come across several instances of the following deprecation.

https://deprecations-app-prod.herokuapp.com/deprecations/v3.x/#toc_ember-meta-descriptor-on-object

> Use defineProperty to define computed properties
>
> until: 3.5.0
>
> id: ember-meta.descriptor-on-object

Although uncommon, it is possible to assign computed properties directly to objects and have them be implicitly computed from eg Ember.get. As part of supporting ES5 getter computed properties, assigning computed properties directly is deprecated. You should replace these assignments with calls to defineProperty.

These deprecations display in the browser console as:

> `DEPRECATION: [DEPRECATED] computed property 'session' was not set on object '<app@component:component1::ember439>' via 'defineProperty' [deprecation id: ember-meta.descriptor-on-object] See https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v3.x#toc_use-defineProperty-to-define-computed-properties for more details.`
>
> `DEPRECATION: [DEPRECATED] computed property 'gStories' was not set on object '<app@component:component2::ember427>' via 'defineProperty' [deprecation id: ember-meta.descriptor-on-object] See https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v3.x#toc_use-defineProperty-to-define-computed-properties for more details.`

## component1:

#### HBS:

```
<div>
  {{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
    <h2>Signed in</h2>
  {{else}}
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    {{signup-dialog}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

#### JS:

The session service is from ember-simple-auth:
http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/SessionService.html

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { service } from 'ember-decorators/service';

export default class Component1 extends Component {
  @service('session') session;
}
```

## component2:

#### HBS:

```
{{#if gStories}}
  <h2>
    Stories
  </h2>

  {{#each gStories as |story|}}
    {{story-component story=story}}
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

#### JS:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from 'ember-decorators/object';
import { argument } from '@ember-decorators/argument';

export default class Component2 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }

  @argument
  stories = null;

  @computed('stories')
  get gStories() {
    let stories = this.get('stories');
    let gStories = [];
    stories.forEach((story) => {
      "use strict";

      if (story.get('type') === 'g') {
        gStories.pushObject(story);
      }
    });

    return gStories;
  }
}
```

I'm hoping that someone can show me how to resolve the two cases above in which I can clean up the remainder of my application. Perhaps there is a better coding practice that I should be using instead as the deprecation states "Although uncommon".

Any additional background information on this deprecation would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

## Update:

It was brought to my attention that it was perhaps @ember-decorators causing the issue. I found it an easier path to remove them from the examples in question and see if those deprecations were no longer thrown.

## component1:

#### HBS:

```
<div>
  {{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
    <h2>Signed in</h2>
  {{else}}
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    {{signup-dialog}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

#### JS:

The session service is from ember-simple-auth:
http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/SessionService.html

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import {inject as service} from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  session: service('session'),
});
```

## component2:

#### HBS:

```
{{#if gStories}}
  <h2>
    Stories
  </h2>

  {{#each gStories as |story|}}
    {{story-component story=story}}
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

#### JS:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
  stories: null,

  gStories: computed('stories', function() {
    let stories = this.get('stories');
    let gStories = [];
    stories.forEach((story) => {
      "use strict";

      if (story.get('type') === 'g') {
        gStories.pushObject(story);
      }
    });

    return gStories;
  })
});
```

The good news is that resolved the deprecation for component2. The bad news is it did not for component1.

Deprecation on session remains:

> `DEPRECATION: [DEPRECATED] computed property 'session' was not set on object '<app@component:component1::ember439>' via 'defineProperty' [deprecation id: ember-meta.descriptor-on-object] See https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v3.x#toc_use-defineProperty-to-define-computed-properties for more details.`

Thoughts?

Comment: Could this be related to `@ember-decorators`? Do you use the latest version?

Comment: I've seen that deprecation error if using a computed property in a setter, e.g. `this.set('name', computed(function() {})`. Maybe an old version of `@ember-decorators` is doing something similar internally?

Comment: Took both of your suggestions and looked at my `@ember-decorators` package. It is back leveled and a quick update was not pretty so I took a different approach. I've updated my post with changes to the components to remove the decorators from the components in question. Was able to clear up one of the two deprecations.

Comment: For component1, could it be the `{{signup-dialog}}` helper that actually does trigger this deprecation?

Comment: It might be related to your parent component or controller if you pass session as a computed param. How do you create an instance of component1?

Comment: Only can guess that something was caught up somewhere or didn't completely refresh because starting things up today...fresh ember serve..clean browser and the deprecation on session for component1 is gone with the updated changes. Going to go with `@ember-decorators` (at least older versions) underlying implementation is computed properties. Thanks all - I overlooked that possibility!

Answer (score 0):

`@ember-decorators` was the culprit since removing the references to `@ember-decorators` cleared up the deprecation warning. The underlying implementation of `@ember-decorators` (at least older versions - 1.3.4 in this case) must be using computed properties.